# CSS Polygon/Shape: Pitch Circle

Tags: html, css, polygon

Is it possible to get a shape like this in CSS:

[image]

I'd like to set the background color and border color separately.

Comment: You want SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG

Comment: I think this is possible through CSS, which would be convenient for the borders. I'll try to get a fiddle up shortly.

Comment: here's the closest I got: http://jsfiddle.net/nVf7F/ - using [this approach](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/) by Lea Verou. Unless you use multiple elements, you can't really do it with a single element and CSS, simply because applying these borders can only be done through gradients and stuff like that, but with this technique (which is the only one I know) you'll get overlap from the background gradients, thus breaking the shape. I think you'll need to use SVG lol xD

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, at least you can get very close to it:
[image]

How you make it is to make the actual shape using the border of the div:

```
div{
border-left:150px solid transparent; 
    border-right:150px solid transparent;
    border-top:300px solid lavender;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;

}
```

Since you are using the border to create the shape, you must use div:after to create the border of the border!

```
div:before{
border-left:150px solid transparent; 
    border-right:150px solid transparent;
    border-top:320px solid red;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:-310px;
    left:-160px;
    content:'';
    z-index:-1;
    width:220px;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/55RzL/)

To add text to it, you must give the text absolute positioning:

```
div p{
    position:absolute;
    top:-200px;
    left:50px;

}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/55RzL/1/)